# Searching one field from several mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, database, search

I have several databases represents the companies we work.
In every database there are fields which we work on.
And in the fields area, there are field infos and our engineer who worked at that field.

I need to search all databases and filter with engineer names, to get a list of fields he worked.

I hope I could explain.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You're going to have to manually write queries to search each table in each database. The whole idea of database schemas and tables is that they are distinct wrappers for data, which can't be implicitly joined.